# Struggling with adding dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Trying to make a discord bot with C++, tried to add the library D++ and got a squiggly.

I've made a folder, put the library inside, and added it to includePath, but when I put in the code #include <dpp.h> I get a strange error that reads:

```
 cannot open source file "variant" (dependency of "dpp.h")
```

Checked others solutions but nothing has worked so far,

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dpp.h> //Error here

int main() {  
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My c-cpp-properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/libraries/libdpp-10.0.23-win64/include/dpp-10.0/dpp",
                "C:/MinGW/bin/"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Did you check your ``dpp`` dependencies are actually into the correct folder?

Comment: You're missing the standard library include paths from your settings

Comment: `"C:/MinGW/bin/"` is definitely wrong as an include path.